# Why is my interface font larger with LibreOffice than with other GTK applications?

Tags: fonts, libreoffice

I installed LibreOffice and the libreoffice-gtk package. The GUI has the same appearance as other GTK applications, however, the fonts in the interface appear to be 1.5 to 2 times larger than those in other GTK applications.

- I had this problem with OpenOffice.org and after upgrading to LibreOffice.
- I set the font using the `xfce4-appearance-settings` application.
- The font size difference appears no matter what font or size is selected.
- Restarting the computer does not solve the problem.

Debian 6
LibreOffice 3.5.4.2
XFce 4.6.2

Comment: Doesn't OO/LO have an option to zoom the interface in its preferences dialog somewhere? I don't have access to a running copy right now so cannot check, but I do seem to recall something like that.

Comment: In `Tools` --> `Options` --> `LiberOffice` --> `View` there is a `Scaling` option, but it is listed at 100%. When I reduce it to 80%, the lowest possible value, the fonts are smaller, but are still larger than in the other applications.

Comment: It might also be incorrect DPI setting on your display - not all applications treat it in the same way.